# Users will get Unicorn Carpal Tunnel from mining unicoins

Tags: discussion, fun, unicoins

Those darn unicoins, as a result so many people will be getting carpal tunnel syndrome.

[image: unicorn]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the unicorns' fault!

Blame unicoins- their golden sheen will drive even the most stalwart programmer to the depths of despair. Beware! Their allure is beautiful and deadly (if your arm falls off from Unicorn Carpal Tunnel Syndrome and/or gets infected).

A tip- make sure that you replace your <strike>fingers</strike> arms often. That solved the issue for me. If you can't do that, start with the arm that you like least, and move on to the next worst one.

Comment: haha true true! :P

Comment: I tried to accept your edit but wasn't sure how...

Comment: @user23948732856 No problem! :)

Comment: Better replace whole arm in order to avoid Carpal Tunnel Syndrome. Or take a 364 day unicoin leave.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe And return just in time for April Fools? Coincidence? I think not!